# How can I use non-Python dependencies for my Django Zappa project?

Tags: django, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, zappa, mecab

I'm using a Python package called [natto-py](https://github.com/buruzaemon/natto-py) which requires a non-python Japanese tokeniser called [MeCab](https://github.com/jordwest/mecab-docs-en).

Is it possible to use this for my Zappa project? How can MeCab be installed on Lambda (since pip does not work)?

Django 1.10 & Python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the binary in the same directory as your zappa project and zappa will zip it up and ship it to Lambda.

Since you are compiling your own binary, I would strongly recommend [using a local docker environment for zappa](https://blog.zappa.io/posts/docker-zappa-and-python3) to more closely match the AWS Lambda environment.

Also if your binary is big and will make your Lambda package bigger than 50MB then be sure to use the [`slim_handler` option.](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#large-projects)

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by 'drop the binary'? Sorry, I'm new to this. Do I have to install MeCab in the Docker environment?

Comment: You need to download the source of MeCab, and compile (in the Docker environment) to a binary.  then put that binary into a sub directory of your zappa project and ensure your python code can find it.  Then when you do a zappa deploy, zappa will collect it and deploy into the same subdirectory for the lambda function

Comment: This sounds a bit complicated. I have downloaded a mecab.tar.gz file, how should I compile this into a binary? I see a zappa_project/ve/bin directory, is that where I should put the binary file?

Comment: probably zappa_project/ve/lib is the place? (/ve is the virtual environment directory)